# Creating all pairs of list of values in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a small map-reduce program I'm writing for hadoop, one element of the program is to create all pairs of a list. For example if the input for the program is:

```
item1 tag1  
item2 tag1  
item3 tag2  
item4 tag1  
item5 tag2
```

My map function creates a `<tag, item>` pair, so the reducer receives `<tag, List<item>>` as its input. My goal is for the output from the reducer to be:

```
item1-item2 tag1  
item1-item4 tag1  
item2-item4 tag1  
item3-item5 tag2
```

So essentially, for every list of values, to create all the possible pairs, and make each pair a key.
I have found a solution that works, but it relies on copying the list into memory and iterating over it. This might be a problem since my dataset can be very large:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
                         throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Text t : values) {
        list.add(t.toString());
    }
    for (int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<list.size(); j++) {
            out.set(list.get(i) + "-" + list.get(j))
            context.write(out, one);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative, or more efficient way of doing it in hadoop?
I do not want to be copying each list into memory.

I've been trying to come up with something creative like using another map-reduce step, but cannot seem to find something that works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reducer does get all of that data, but that data is actually written to disk and is only brought into memory as you iterate through the Iteratable of values. In fact, the object that is returned by that iteration is reused for each value: the fields and other state are simply replaced before the object is handed to you.

That means you have to explicitly copy the value object in order to have all value objects in memory at the same time.

When i look at your code it seems you are not saving the item pairs in memory. You are writing out the item pairs directly so you should be good.